# How to open a new Jframe and close the firstt Jframe from the new Jframe by clicking button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, action, frame

By click 1 JButton("1- open 2nd Frame") It Opens the 2nd-frame, but when I try to close the 2nd-frame and 1st-Frame at the same time by JButton("2- close current Frame and 1st Frame"), it just closes the 2nd-frame not the 1st one.
Please advice how to close two Frames at the same time.  Not using "System.exit(0);"

The First JFrame code :

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Frame2Frame {
public JFrame frmFrame;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Frame2Frame window = new Frame2Frame();
                window.frmFrame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Frame2Frame() {
    initialize();
}
/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmFrame = new JFrame();
    frmFrame.setTitle("1st Frame");
    frmFrame.setBounds(100, 100, 333, 174);
    frmFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);  
    JButton btnToFrame = new JButton("1- open 2nd Frame");
    btnToFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Frame1Frame F1F = new Frame1Frame<Object>();
            F1F.setVisible(true);
            new Frame2Frame().setVisible(false);
            dispose();          
        }
    });
    btnToFrame.setBounds(83, 52, 147, 23);
    frmFrame.getContentPane().add(btnToFrame);
}
protected static void addWindowListener(WindowAdapter windowAdapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
public static void setVisible(boolean b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
}
```

The Second JFrame code :

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Frame1Frame<frmFrame> extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
public JFrame frmFrame;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Frame1Frame frame = new Frame1Frame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Frame1Frame() {
    setTitle("2nd Frame");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 389, 145);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("2- close current Frame and 1st           Frame");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



            setVisible(false);
            dispose();

        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(46, 35, 260, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
}
}
```

Thanks for your reply in advance.

Comment: Why don't you consider Dialog instead of multiple frames? just asking..

Comment: There are multiple ways you might do this, but the question is why?

Answer (score 0):

Have Frame1Frame import Frame2Frame and than do
`frmFrame.dispose();`

This should be called right before

```
`dispose();`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunate when I click on  "1- open 2nd Frame", it opens second frame but it close the first one.  The first frame should not be close when thee 2nd frame opens.  When "2- close current Frame and 1st Frame" both frame should close at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

How to close a JFrame and open another one when a button is clicked.

Once you are inside your action listener do the following:

1) Make the other frame disappear:
if you want to permanently dispose of it and not access it after do:

```
        F1F.setVisible(false);
        dispose();
        new Frame2Frame().setVisible(true);
```

This should permanently dispose of the first frame and make the second visible.